# Why use a variable named 'vent' in a backbone global event despatcher

Tags: backbone.js

I have seen this in numerous places now when people are creating an application wide event despatcher.

```
var vent = {};
_.extend(vent, Backbone.Events);
```

Why is everyone using the name 'vent'.  It seems to me that it is event minus the e.  Are they using it because event is a reserved work?

Any reasons for such a stupid name for an event despatcher?  Is there some special meaning to this name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably just convention from the [maronette.js project](http://marionettejs.com/).

https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/0c62b6e5cb63763b388a3d7af7df5ad4a64adb33/src/marionette.application.js#L10

Maybe they like it because "vent" is a verb? I prefer "emit" personally and [event is not a reserved keyword](http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm).